# Java: Char Array not working

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class testARRAY
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      char[] charArray;

      //creating the method
      charArray = getCharArray();
      System.out.println(charArray);
   }

      public static char[] getCharArray()
      {
         char array = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

         return array;
      }
}
```

here is the output error

```
testARRAY.java:16: error: illegal initializer for char
         char array = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
                      ^
testARRAY.java:18: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to char[]
         return array;
                ^
2 errors
```

I'm just trying to practice Java. I'm not an advanced programmer, so please explain to me with details.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: What do you think `char` is? What do you think a `String` is? How do you declare arrays?

Comment: `char[] array = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}`

Comment: `char` and `char[]` are different things. You need the second one

Comment: I must say I don't quite understand the rabid downvoting on questions like these. Sure it's an extremely simple and perhaps not very interesting question, but at least it's a valid and specific question, with all relevant details given. There are questions on SO that are far worse.

Comment: As already stated by many, you are confusing chars and strings as well as chars and char arrays. Please don't ignore what the compiler tells you... it tells you for a reason. You just have to learn to understand what it's trying to tell you. You have to find where is the misunderstanding between you and the compiler which can be done by looking for what is different, like when you say "Do you like cheese?" and somebody answers "Which peas?", you have to understand that obviously the issue is cheese vs. peas and not saying "Why do you ask *which*, you are not making any sense".

Answer (score 6):

```
char[] charArray ={ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
```

You forgot the `[]`, and you need single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the type of array to an actual array, instead of just `char`. Furthermore, your one-line instantiation I think should look like the following:

```
char[] array = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
```

Though `new char[]` might not be necessary, it's just how I've always done it.

Comment: It's not necessary when it's the RHS of a variable declaration. Only the `[]` needs to be added.